# How to run multiple commands over sudo using another user

Tags: linux, bash

I want to do something like below

```
ssh -t 10.x.xx.xxx "sudo -s -u user1 /bin/bash -c 'tar --warning=none -xf abc.tgz;cd abc/def;'"
```

But it gives me the following error

tar: You must specify one of the `-Acdtrux' or`--test-label'  options
Try `tar --help' or`tar --usage' for more information.

Comment: The `cd` command is fairly pointless; the shell in which you change the working directory exits immediately after the command is executed.

Comment: @chepner Actually there are many other commands following tar, just for example I added "cd" command. So how do I make sure that commands after tar are also run as user1.

Comment: It's a little tricky; you roughly need to 1) run tar 2) do anything else you want 3) start the interactive shell, so that something is still running to prevent `ssh` from exiting and logging you out. It would be much simpler if you could log in as `user1` instead, but that would require you having the password, as opposed to using `sudo` with your own password. (Unless you don't need to stay logged in; I just assumed that from the `cd`.)

Comment: I can't reproduce this, but it seems like a tar error rather than a problem with using multiple commands.

Comment: Depending on the implementation of `tar`, you might just need `tar --warning=none xf abc.tgz` (no hyphen preceding the `x`).

Comment: What is the OS on the remote system?

Comment: @glennjackman : OS is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.3

Comment: @tushR the problem with your command is that the cd is outside of the single quotes, not inside

Comment: @thatotherguy : that was a typo, updated the question.

Comment: @tushR replace it with an echo so you can tell whether or not the command runs. cd has no output on success.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you just need to omit the `-` prior to the `x` in the `tar` command. Otherwise, what you have is more or less correct, although a little longer than it needs to be. Unless `user1` has a login shell other than `/bin/bash` and you *need* to use `bash`, you can shorten the command to

```
ssh 10.x.xx.xxx 'sudo -u user1 -s "tar --warning=none xf abc.tgz; ..."'
```

The string argument to `-s` is automatically passed as the argument to `-c` for whatever shell is started by `-s`.